# How to get out of Emergency mode in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, fstab

When I boot ubuntu, I get into 'emergency mode' or 'maintenance mode'
I have dual boot and grub with windows 10 and Ubuntu installed.

This is a video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7D4sUYXQmw) that I found that basically describes the problem I have.

In 'emergency mode' terminal I use the following commands (as is in the video):

```
cd /
ls
cd etc
ls
sudo chmod 777 fstab
ls
sudo nano fstab
```

Then I get the following as my etc/fstab/ as per the video:

```
# <file system> <mount point> <type> <option>      <dump>     <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=ef7a36df-8075-43a8-9cf3-xy236ef3ec5e /         ext4        error=remount-ro 0      1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=CA45-3112   /boot/efi     vfat     umask=0077   0   1 
# /home was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=983748b1-72a3-46d6-a07f-4c30e1aa74b2 /home     ext4       defaults         0      2   
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=2adfc063-9905-4bd5-9c44-3383cffd5e2c none      swap       sw         0      0
```

---

I put a '#' symbol on the line with '/boot/efi' as the video and previous comments recommended on the askubuntu board:

```
#UUID=CA45-3112   /boot/efi     vfat     umask=0077   0   1
```

I saved it and restarted Ubuntu, with no sign of getting out of 'emergency mode'.

Comment: Did it ever work, or is this a new install? Commenting out the EFI partition in fstab is unlikely to fix anything. If you can run `lsblk -f` and paste its output into your question (copy and paste, not a screen shot) we can at least verify if your fstab matches the partitions on your system.

Comment: What is the actual question ?

Comment: Just reinstall. Not much else you can do! To save your data in the future, use Deja Dup to backup to external drive (you can set it to backup at a certain time with a certain interval).  If you are using Ubuntu Server, use `fsync` (`sudo fsync /path/to/backup /path/to/save/backup/to`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ubuntu USB-stick you used to install Ubuntu. With GParted you can see the UUID (rightclick on the EFI-partition) and copy it to a text-editor or write it on paper. 
With the method you saw in the video change the UUID in `fstab`. Now don't put the `#` in front of the line. Save the file, reboot. Now the EFI-partition should be recognized correctly. Hope this helps you.